# Reversing singly linked list using recursion

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I have written code to reverse singly linked list using recursion. It is working fine on lists of length less than or equal to 174725. But on lists of length greater than 174725 it gives a segmentation fault(Segmentation fault: 11) while reversing it via reverse() call. Can someone please explain this to me ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
  public:
    int val;
    Node *next;
};

class Sll
{
  public:
    Node *head;

  private:
    void reverse(Node *node);

  public:
    Sll();
    void insert_front(int key);
    void reverse();
    void print();
};

void Sll::reverse(Node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;
    Node *rest = node->next;
    if (rest == NULL)
    {
        head = node;
        return;
    }
    reverse(rest);
    rest->next = node;
    node->next = NULL;
    return;
}

Sll::Sll()
{
    head = NULL;
}

void Sll::insert_front(int key)
{
    Node *newnode = new Node;
    newnode->val = key;
    newnode->next = head;
    head = newnode;
    return;
}

void Sll::print()
{
    Node *temp = head;
    while (temp)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}

void Sll::reverse()
{
    reverse(head);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    Sll newList = Sll();
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) newList.insert_front(i + 1);
    newList.reverse();
    // newList.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

List reversing function must be tail-recursive, otherwise it is going to overflow the stack when recursing over a long list, like you observe. Also, it needs to be compiled with optimisations enabled or with `-foptimize-sibling-calls` gcc option.

Tail-recursive version:

```
Node* reverse(Node* n, Node* prev = nullptr) {
    if(!n)
        return prev;
    Node* next = n->next;
    n->next = prev;
    return reverse(next, n);
}
```

An iterative list reversion can be more easily inlined though and it does not require any optimization options:

```
inline Node* reverse(Node* n) {
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    while(n) {
        Node* next = n->next;
        n->next = prev;
        prev = n;
        n = next;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

Comment: "recursive function generally cannot be inlined." Why not ?

Comment: Here is my new reverse() call which is coded in tail recursive manner. But still the same problem persists.

Comment: @TusharVatsal It needs to be compiled with optimisations enabled or with `-foptimize-sibling-calls` gcc option.

Comment: @ Maxim Egorushkin Even after applying this optimization I am getting segmentation fault

Comment: @TusharVatsal I do not get the segfault with `-O3`. Did not test other optimization levels.